# Tranferring values into form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working with Wapka.mobi which is based on xhtml. I want to transfer a string from a span into a form. Here is what i used

```
 if(':user-prvar-625:'=='') {
 } else { 
   document.getElementsByName("location")[0].innerHTML='From :user-prvar-625:';}
```

and below this i have

```
function checkin(){ 
    stat=document.getElementsByName("blog_body")
    [0].value;loc=document.getElementsByName("loc")[0].value; if(':user-prvar-625:'=='') {} 
else {
    document.getElementsByName("blog_body")   
    [0].value=stat+'[checkin]'+loc+'[/checkin]';
   } 
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in a fiddle and share us.

Answer (score 0):

Are stat and loc the spans?

Use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`!